# PRAW get_redditor() slow?

Tags: python, performance, reddit, praw

Has anyone else noticed that get_redditor() method of praw is a bit slow?
I started working with it yesterday and when I started noticing the speed drops
 I decided to do a bit of a test. I use the following code :

```python
import praw
import time

time1 = 0
time2 = 0

print('Initial reddit setup')
time1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
user_agent = ('Reddit Checker 0.1 by /u/NinjaXI')
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent)
time2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print(time1)
print(time2)
print(time2 - time1)
print('===================================================================')

print('Get Subreddit Python')
time1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
pythonSub = r.get_subreddit('Python')
time2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print(time1)
print(time2)
print(time2 - time1)
print('===================================================================')

print('Get hot 10')
time1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
pythonSub.get_hot(limit=10)
time2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print(time1)
print(time2)
print(time2 - time1)
print('===================================================================')

print('Get Redditor NinjaXI')
time1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
me = r.get_redditor('NinjaXI')
time2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print(time1)
print(time2)
print(time2 - time1)
print('===================================================================')

print('Get submitted 10')
time1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
me.get_submitted(limit=10)
time2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print(time1)
print(time2)
print(time2 - time1)
print('===================================================================')
```

This outputs :

```
Initial reddit setup
1421319134782
1421319134783
1
===================================================================
Get Subreddit Python
1421319134783
1421319134783
0
===================================================================
Get hot 10
1421319134783
1421319134783
0
===================================================================
Get Redditor NinjaXI
1421319134783
1421319137402
2619
===================================================================
Get submitted 10
1421319137402
1421319137402
0
===================================================================
```

As you can see to use get_redditor() takes(in this run) 2.6 seconds longer than get_subreddit(). On average the time is between 2 and 2.6 seconds everytime, but get_subreddit() only goes as high as 1ms. Is there something I'm doing? Is it a known issue with praw/reddit api? Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: I think the other functions [return lazy objects](http://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/lazy-loading.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, just call get_redditor('username', fetch=False) and it works. Please post as answer. Quite weird that I'd need to specify that for one and not the other. Gonna see if I can report it to the dev somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRAW's getters typically [return lazy objects](http://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/lazy-loading.html), meaning that they only request data from Reddit's servers when you actually try to use the object. This is consistent with your very fast function calls -- everything is happening locally. Your `get_redditor()` call is probably requesting the data immediately (though I couldn't say why; according to the doc, it should be lazy as well).

Comment: The get_redditor() method can also load lazy objects it just requires passing fetch=False as an argument for whatever reason.